# Setting up VCR with Cucumber & Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, vcr

I have the vcr and webmock gems installed.

features/support/vcr_setup.rb:

```
require 'vcr'

VCR.configure do |c|
  c.cassette_library_dir = 'vcr_cassettes'
  c.hook_into :webmock
end
```

features/step_definitions/user.rb:

```
VCR.use_cassette('login to shopify') do
  Given /^I am a logged in user$/ do
    @shop = create(:shop)
    visit root_path
    fill_in :shop, :with => @shop.shopify_domain
    click_button 'Install'
    expect(page).to have_content("We'll automatically")
  end
end
```

When I run my suite, I'm getting the alert that I am making an HTTP request. Which step am I missing to properly record the first cassette so that I can re-use for future tests?

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the absolute path of your `cassette_library_dir` configuration. Like this:

```
  c.cassette_library_dir = Rails.root.join('test', 'fixtures', 'vcr_cassettes')
```

(Whatever the correct path for `vcr_cassettes` is in your application)

So, your `features/support/vcr_setup.rb` becomes like this:

```
VCR.configure do |c|
  c.cassette_library_dir = Rails.root.join('test', 'fixtures', 'vcr_cassettes')
  c.hook_into :webmock
end
```

Comment: Hmmm. tried that with no luck. I feel like I'm missing one of the setup steps, like requiring it somewhere or something

Comment: "Ensure this file is required by your test suite before any
of the tests are run."  - How do I do this? Does this just mean require 'vcr_setup' in my features/step_definitions/user.rb file?

Comment: Try that and see if that works. Without seeing the whole thing, its hard to guess for me :(